# Bootstrap: inserting margins between text boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text field and a button with the following code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" action="{!! route('buyer_bid_create', ['id' => $lot->id ]) !!}">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_value" id="bid_value" placeholder="VAT number">
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm VAT number</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

The result is shown below:

[image: bootstrap issue]

How can I ensure a whiteline between the textbox and the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you could add some custom CSS on form-group

```
.form-inline .form-group {
margin-bottom: yourValue;
}
```

Only do that if you want to apply the margin to all form-group elements

Or you could add a new class to the element and apply styling that way. Use this method if you only want to add the margin to specific form-group elements

HTML

```
<div class="form-group form-group--margin-bottom">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_value" id="bid_value" placeholder="VAT number">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-inline .form-group--margin-bottom {
margin-bottom: yourValue
}
```

You need to include the .form-inline class to override bootstrap's specific targeting of that element. I wouldn't advise using !important unless absolutely necessary as it came make the CSS harder to understand in the future

I have a [working version of the 2nd option on codepen](http://codepen.io/literallyluke/pen/GqbORR)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy to help

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a margin-bottom to the input wrapper with a separate class.

You'll need to use !important because .form-inline .form-group has a margin-bottom: 0 property.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" action="{!! route('buyer_bid_create', ['id' => $lot->id ]) !!}">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
   <div class="form-group margin-bottom">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_value" id="bid_value" placeholder="VAT number">
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm VAT number</button>
   </div>
</form>

.margin-bottom{
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
```

http://codepen.io/tomanagle/pen/rLEGXz

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect!